# Private folder on Internal/external storage on android

Tags: android, file

I want to create a private folder for my app data. This folder has to be deleted automatically when the app is removed from the device. According to http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html, I have to create a private folder. How can I achieve this. My code below. Folder is not deleted when the app is removed.

```
 public static String getAppFilePath(Context context) {

        String path = "";
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath();

            path += "/myFolder";

        } else {

            ContextWrapper c = new ContextWrapper(context);
            path = c.getFilesDir().getPath();
        }
        File ret = new File(path);
        if (!ret.exists()) {
            ret.mkdirs();
        }
        return path;
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you are doing it wrong.

from the documentation you pointed:

> If you want to save files that are **private to your app**, you can
>   acquire the appropriate directory **by calling getExternalFilesDir()**
>   and passing it a name indicating the type of directory you'd like.
>   Each directory created this way is added to a parent directory that
>   encapsulates all your app's external storage files, which the system
>   deletes when the user uninstalls your app.
>
> For example, here's a method you can use to create a directory for an
>   individual photo album:
>
> ```
> public File getAlbumStorageDir(Context context, String albumName) {
>     // Get the directory for the app's private pictures directory. 
>     File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(
>             Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
>     if (!file.mkdirs()) {
>         Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
>     }
>     return file;
> }
> ```
>
> If none of the pre-defined sub-directory names suit your files, you
>   can instead call getExternalFilesDir() and pass null. This returns the
>   root directory for your app's private directory on the external
>   storage.
>
> **Remember that getExternalFilesDir() creates a directory inside a directory that is deleted when the user uninstalls your app.** If the
>   files you're saving should remain available after the user uninstalls
>   your app—such as when your app is a camera and the user will want to
>   keep the photos—you should instead use
>   getExternalStoragePublicDirectory().

so basically you need to use `getExternalFilesDir`function in the example above to get it deleted when app in uninstalled.

---

according to documentation for [`getExternalFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))

> **Parameters**
>
> type  The type of files directory to return. May be `null` for
>   the root of the files directory or one of the following constants for
>   a subdirectory: `DIRECTORY_MUSIC`, `DIRECTORY_PODCASTS`,
>   `DIRECTORY_RINGTONES`, `DIRECTORY_ALARMS`, `DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS`,
>   `DIRECTORY_PICTURES`, or `DIRECTORY_MOVIES`.

so apart from predefined types you can use `null` for root of the directory.

Comment: Yes, I read that part in the reference, but what Environment. variable should I use? I have documents and couple of images.

Comment: check updated answer, you can use `null` for root as there is no subdirectory for documents. for pictures use `DIRECTORY_PICTURES`

Comment: Why does the javadoc say the following:
"There is no security enforced with these files. For example, any application holding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE can write to these files."

It seems like any app with storage access that knows my package name could access these files?

Comment: @laim2003 use `getFilesDir()` instead if security of files is your concern

Answer (score -1):

In simple words you cannot.
It is not possible as you cannot handle event after uninstalling the App.